# HTML script not working

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please explain why am I not getting this alert message when clicked on the button?
I just started learning HTML and this is the code given in my book which is supposed to work but it is not working when i execute it.
What is the problem? I am using Mozilla Firefox Beta version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>This is a test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is a test Paragraph</h1>
    <button type="button"
    onclick="alert('You've clicked me.')">Click me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: the book you are using may be outdated. For html5 you can start your html file by using <!DOCTYPE html><html>... the <?xml tag you are using is not needed. hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Yes it does make sense. I'll find an updated article online to study from as I can't afford to buy another book.
Any suggestion's for free tutorials would really be appreciated.

Comment: the book you have will be a great starting point. Then its simply a matter of looking at the page source of other sites and seeing what you can implement yourself. Hopefully your book also introduces CSS,.. http://www.w3.org/ has all the HTML information you could ever need, but is quite technical. I would recommend w3schools, but then other users would probably get upset! It's useful for tag references however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You need to escape the apostrophe in "you've".

```
alert('You\'ve clicked me.')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change line

`onclick="alert('You've clicked me.')">Click me!</button>`

to

`onclick="alert('You\'ve clicked me.')">Click me!</button>`